# Variable containing a path which is not being interpreted correctly?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF

    IF EXIST comandosAEjecutar.tpl (DEL comandosAEjecutar.tpl)

    ECHO Procesando archivos a subir...
    FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%g IN (config.tpl) DO ECHO open %%g>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
    FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%g IN (config.tpl) DO ECHO %%g>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
    FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%g IN (config.tpl) DO ECHO %%g>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
    ECHO binary>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
    FOR /f "tokens=4 delims=," %%g IN (config.tpl) DO ECHO cd %%g>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
    FOR /f "tokens=5 delims=," %%p IN (config.tpl) DO @SET pathLocal=%%p

    FOR /r . %%g IN (%pathLocal%\*.txt %pathLocal%\*.zip) DO ECHO delete %%~nxg>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
    FOR /r . %%g IN (%pathLocal%\*.txt %pathLocal%\*.zip) DO ECHO put %%~nxg>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl

    ECHO bye>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl

    ECHO Comienzo de la sesion FTP...

    FTP -i -s:"comandosAEjecutar.tpl"

    ECHO Finalizado.
    PAUSE
    EXIT
```

The actual problem is in the following lines:

```
    FOR /f "tokens=5 delims=," %%p IN (config.tpl) DO @SET pathLocal=%%p

    FOR /r . %%g IN (%pathLocal%\*.txt %pathLocal%\*.zip) DO ECHO delete %%~nxg>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
    FOR /r . %%g IN (%pathLocal%\*.txt %pathLocal%\*.zip) DO ECHO put %%~nxg>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
```

I know that the variable "pathLocal" is being set correctly, as I did an ECHO and it showed the correct path, something like: \\red\C\pc\pc.com\serv\down\bol

The problem is that the two following lines are not interpreting the variable as a path, as they are producing no results, when I do have .txt and .zip files on that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is the pathlocal variable being in the parenthesis, try moving it after the /r

```
FOR /r %pathLocal% %%g IN (*.txt *.zip) DO ECHO delete %%~nxg>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
FOR /r %pathLocal% %%g IN (*.txt *.zip) DO ECHO put %%~nxg>> comandosAEjecutar.tpl
```

Comment: In case pathLocal contains spaces, you should quote it too.